# How can I break a variable definition across multiple lines in a Makefile without spaces?

Tags: makefile

Consider the following Makefile

```
CP = .:${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.2.0.jar:\
${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.2.0.jar:\
${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar:\
${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar:\
${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.2.0.jar\

all:
    echo $(CP)
```

The output of running `make` is

```
.:/home/hduser/Hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.2.0.jar: /home/hduser/Hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.2.0.jar: /home/hduser/Hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar: /home/hduser/Hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar: /home/hduser/Hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.2.0.jar
```

Observe that there are spaces after each `:`.

Is there a way to define the variable `CP` with the line breaks, but without the extraneous space substituting every newline?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to break a string across lines in a makefile without spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246165/how-to-break-a-string-across-lines-in-a-makefile-without-spaces)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s impossible to *prevent* backslash-newline from becoming a space, and it’s clumsy and error-prone to try to remove the spaces afterwards (what if there are supposed to be spaces?), but you can remove each as it’s produced.  This has the significant advantage of working anywhere, even **inside function calls**.  The trick is to embed the space produced in an expression that expands to nothing.

`$(call foo)` with empty/undefined `foo` would work, but we can do better: variable names can contain spaces in (GNU) Make.  It’s hard to assign to them, but we don’t want to anyway.  So then we can shorten it to `$(a b)` or even `$(a )`; a backslash-newline will be turned into a space before the lookup.  But even a single space works:

```
foo=bar$(\
)baz
```

Finally, the parentheses may be omitted for a single-character variable name:

```
foo=bar$\
baz
```

…which finally looks like we are (fully) escaping the newline rather than using it somehow.  So long as no one *assigns* to “ ” (which is even crazier than *using* it!), anyway.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Just a clarification: Is the concern that someone assigns to a space character or a newline character?

Comment: It's possible to assign to either one, but here it's the space that matters.  It's easy to _read_ `$( )`, but difficult to even read `$(\n)`: there's no escape sequence to give a newline _in_ the variable name.

Comment: See comments from the GNU Make maintainer in a related question https://stackoverflow.com/a/50863019/579141; though this technique works in current versions of Make, it is not (yet) guaranteed in future versions.  A ticket requesting official support for this technique has been submitted.

Comment: It's a fair concern.  Still, while POSIX doesn't require support for spaces in variable names (at least while _creating_ them), its [description of Makefile processing](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html#tag_20_76_13_05) seems pretty clear that there is no other legitimate interpretation here, so change seems unlikely.

Comment: GNU Make 4.3 now documents the "dollar sign/backslash/newline" method for splitting lines: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50862827/579141

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is to use `$\<newline>` to split the line.  Using the
following fake paths for brevity:

```
CP = one$\
     two$\
     three$\
     four

all:
    echo $(CP)
```

The output will be "onetwothreefour" with no spaces.  This is because GNU Make
will replace backslash-newline-whitespace with a single space, making the
assignment to `CP` be equivalent to:

```
CP = one$ two$ three$ four
```

From
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reference.html#Reference: "A
dollar sign followed by a character other than a dollar sign, open-parenthesis
or open-brace treats that single character as the variable name."
So the `$<space>` pairs are expansions of the variable whose name is a single
space character.  Since this variable is not defined by default, it will expand
to the empty string.

Note that the variable `CP` will still contain the `$<space>` pairs until it
is expanded.  Most of the time, this doesn't matter, but if your makefile
depends on using `$(value CP)` to process the underlying (unexpanded) value,
the above technique may provide surprising results.

Also, the recently released GNU Make 4.3 now explicitly documents this
technique for splitting lines (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Splitting-Lines):

> Splitting Without Adding Whitespace
>
> If you need to split a line but do not want any whitespace added, you can utilize a subtle trick: replace your backslash/newline pairs with the three characters dollar sign/backslash/newline:
>
> ```
> var := one$\
>        word
> ```
>
> After make removes the backslash/newline and condenses the following line into a single space, this is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> var := one$ word
> ```
>
> Then make will perform variable expansion. The variable reference ‘$ ’ refers to a variable with the one-character name “ ” (space) which does not exist, and so expands to the empty string, giving a final assignment which is the equivalent of:
>
> ```
> var := oneword
> ```

Another technique is to launder the value of `CP`.  This requires GNU Make
3.80 or above because it relies on `$(value)` and `$(eval)`.  It makes
use of a few variables and functions for the laundering process.

First, define the variable `empty` to be the empty string and the variables
`space` and `newline` to contain a literal space and newline, respectively:

```
empty :=

space := $(empty) $(empty)

define newline


endef
```

Next, use `$(eval)` to programmatically create a recursively expanded variable
with a given value:

```
# Define recursively expanded variable $1 with value $2.
defineVar = $(eval define $1$(newline)$2$(newline)endef)
```

And define the function `resubst` to repeated substitute one string with
another:

```
# Replace $1 with $2 in $3 until no more changes are made.
resubst = $\
  $(if $(findstring $1,$3),$\
       $(call resubst,$\
              $1,$\
              $2,$\
              $(subst $1,$2,$3)),$\
       $3)
```

These are sufficient to define functions two-dimensionally with arbitrary
newlines and indentation.  The general method comprises three steps:

1. Prepend a newline to the function body;
2. Repeatedly replace newline-space pairs with newlines;
3. Remove all newlines.

The function `def` removes the newline/whitespace line
continuations from the `$(value)` of a recursively expanded
variable defined via `define`/`endef`:

```
# $1 - name of function to redefine as a normalized single-line function.
def = $\
  $(call defineVar,$\
         $1,$\
         $(subst $(newline),$\
                 $(empty),$\
                 $(call resubst,$\
                        $(newline)$(space),$\
                        $(newline),$\
                        $(newline)$(value $1))))
```

Now `def` may be used to post-process a recursively expanded variable.  For
example:

```
define CP
  one
  two
  three
  four
endef
$(call def,CP)
```

Now, `$(value CP)` will return the desired `onetwothreefour`.

The above is a distillation from my article "GNU Make line continuations":
http://drmikehenry.com/gnu-make-line-continuations/

Comment: I had this question open in a browser tab while I wrote my blog article last week, and only noticed composing my answer today that @davis-herring had sneaked in a similar answer yesterday.

Comment: See comments from the GNU Make maintainer in a related question https://stackoverflow.com/a/50863019/579141; though this technique works in current versions of Make, it is not (yet) guaranteed in future versions.  A ticket requesting official support for this technique has been submitted.

Answer (score 3):

Not really; the backslash-newline combination is defined to produce a space. However, if you are using GNU Make, you could simply `$(subst : ,:,$(CP))`.

Comment: I'm on `GNU Make 3.81` but the code you presented does not have the desired effect. The spaces are still there.

Comment: In particular `echo $(subst ,,$(CP))` produces the same output as `echo $(CP)`.

Comment: Sorry; added a colon -- try now?

Comment: Nope, still same output. My earlier Google queries indicates that spaces are generally tricky in Makefiles, which is why I asked whether there's a way to define it without spaces.

Comment: There was supposed to be two spaces after `subst` but I can't test from here and am uncertain whether it would work.

Comment: Alternatively, put it in `define`...`endef` but that will give you a value with actual newlines, which I understand is not what you want. (I could be wrong; I was wondering about that part of your question.)

Comment: No, I don't want actual newlines. I just want my Makefile to be readable.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to necro this a little bit, but I ***think*** this will give you what you're looking for:

```
CP = .:${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.2.0.jar:
CP:=$(CP)${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.2.0.jar:
CP:=$(CP)${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar:
CP:=$(CP)${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar:
CP:=$(CP)${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.2.0.jar
```

This should append the next line onto the value of CP, somewhat different than "+=", which adds a space.

Comment: I the `get *** Recursive variable  references itself (eventually).  Stop.` error with this too.

Comment: @wander95 Interesting.... how many times are you iterating? I've used this method with up to 7 rows, each row being at least 100 characters. I'll try to test out later to see if there's an upper limit on it.

Answer (score 0):

I made it similar to @goodguy5

```
CP:=${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.2.0.jar
CP+=$(CP)${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.2.0.jar
CP+=$(CP)${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar
CP+=$(CP)${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar
CP+=$(CP)${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.2.0.jar
```

Comment: This doesn't work: `Makefile:7: *** Recursive variable 'CP' references itself (eventually).  Stop.`

Comment: It worked for me. Maybe the compiler version is related?

Comment: It will work if the first line uses `CP := ...` not `CP = ...`.  That forces `CP` to be a simply-expanded variable.

Comment: Thanks for the comment